# Issue with proc sql to select large number of files

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I am trying to select a large number of files using the `proc sql` statement below

```
proc sql;
   select cats(libname, ".",memname) into :names separated by " " 
   from dictionary.tables
   where upcase(libname) = "MYLIBNAME";
quit;
```

but when I write `%PUT Data sets: &names;` nothing appears in the log file and I get an error saying the macro `names` is not resolved. Any ideas what is going wrong here?

Comment: is where clause yield any results

Comment: @Kiran I tried withouth `where` clause. Similar issue.

Comment: I tried for SASHELP it worked for me. can you try with SASHELP.VTABLE instead of dictionary.tables

Comment: If I try without the where clause and `SASHELP.VTABLE` it still gives no rows selected and `names` not resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MYLIBNAME` is an invalid libref.  Librefs have a maximum of 8 characters. MYLIBNAME is 9 characters so there will be no librefs defined in your SAS session that can match it.

What happens if you try `libname = "WORK"` or `libname = "SASHELP"` ?  Macro variable `names` will get populated.

Be careful with libraries containing many thousands of tables.  A macro variable can only be 64K-2 characters long.

Comment: Hi Richard, the real libname is actually 8 characters so shouldn't be a problem but that is useful to know! I tried changing `libname="WORK"` and `SASHELP` neither of which populates`names`. Is there anything else that could be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

@Richard answer is perfect. if it is still not working do the following.

1. try outobs =1, just to check with and without where clause

   ```
    proc sql outobs= 1;
    select cats(libname, ".",memname) into :names separated by " " 
     from dictionary.tables
     where upcase(libname) = "SASHELP";
    quit;

   %put &names;
   ```
2. use proc contents, followed by concatenation. it will show error in next step, if your macro variable is longer than 65534

   ```
   PROC CONTENTS DATA=SASHELP._ALL_  out= new(keep=memname libname) noprint; RUN

   proc sql;
   select cats(libname, ".",memname) into :names separated by " " 
     from new;
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I actually realized the issue was a silly mistake. I had set `obs = 0` so there were no observations in the VTABLE and thus no matches (I do this to test other sections of code for snytax and forgot to turn off). Withouth this everything works as expected.